# How can I convert the array to a string variable in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new to Codeigniter and want to display my `state_name` which I believe in an array, but I want the first element in that array to be in a variable and be displayed

I am getting the output as: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [state_name] => XYZ state ) )` 
the output I want is just `XYZ state`

My `controller` goes like this:

```
  public function downloadd()
{   
        $this->load->model('New_model');
        $state_id=$this->input->post('state');   //gets me state_id from my view
        $state_name = $this->New_model->getStatename($state_id); //gets me state_name in form of above output
        print_r($state_name[0]);
        exit;
    }
```

And here is my `model` code:

```
public function getStatename($state_id) {
    
    $this->db->select('state_name');
    $this->db->where('state_id',$state_id);
    $state_name=$this->db->get('states')->result();
    
    return $state_name; //geting users data from db in result array
}
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong, Thanks for any contribution in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit your last two lines of code in your `model` as follows:

```
$ans= $this->db->get('states')->row_array();
return $ans['state_name'];
```

This shall do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

The result value is a array so you should use `row_array` to get first row and check if it exists:

```
public function getStatename($state_id) {
    
    $this->db->select('state_name');
    $this->db->where('state_id',$state_id);

    $row = $this->db->get('states')->row_array();
    if($row)
        return $row['state_name'];
    else {
       //should handle the error since data not found
    }
}
```